# Django remove duplicates from .values_list query while preserving order

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model say `MyModel` which contains a CharField `type`. The model has a default meta ordering which should be preserved. I am using the following query to get the list of types -

```
MyModel.objects.all().values_list('type', flat=True).distinct()
```

However, the types are getting repeated. I can do `.order_by('type').distinct()` but that will change the ordering which I don't want. Is there any way to get the list of types in order without manually creating a list in python? Alternative faster solutions are also welcome.

Django version - 1.11

Comment: Are you sure that the same type is repeated? It might just have a trailing/leading space, etc. or some unicode character that looks very similar to another one.

Comment: It gives me hundreds of values while the `.order_by('type').distinct()` only gives me a few dozen so yes I am sure

Comment: I had read somewhere before that with `.values_list(..).distinct()`, a `order_by` is required for the distinct to work, just wondering if there is any good alternative to it

Comment: no that is only if you need distinct *by a certain field*, but retrieve *other* fields as well, and that only works for PostgreSQL.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem This is the issue I am taking about, which occurs because of the default Meta ordering I specified -
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```py
types = MyModel.objects.all().values_list('type', flat=True).distinct()
```

Then, for python 3.6+:

```py
types = list(dict.fromkeys(types))
```

For previous Python versions, use `OrderedDict`:

```py
types = list(collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(types))
```

Answer (score 0):

Distinct is not matching with type because you don't specified it

use this code

```
MyModel.objects.all().values_list('type', flat=True).distinct("type")
```

instead of this code

```
MyModel.objects.all().values_list('type', flat=True).distinct()
```

Comment: This will give the following error - 
`SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY`

I am not ordering on `type` but on some other field specified in model Meta

Comment: this wont work if the database is not postgres. [distinct(*fields)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) works only with postgres.

Answer (score 0):

You can try for this

```
MyModel.objects.all().values('type', flat=True).order_by('type').distinct()
```

it will work for you

Comment: I need to preserve the default order

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 steps:

First, get the id of the records with unique types and save them in a list:

```py
ids = list(MyModel.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('type').distinct('type'))
```

Then do the filter using the ids:

```py
MyModel.objects.values_list('type', flat=True).filter(id__in=ids)
```

Comment: Yes but this just seems so wasteful for such a simple operation.

Comment: Indeed it is. but in order to remove duplicates, you **must** order the records by the `type` field. There´s no other way (or at least not one I can think of).

Comment: They are a few hundred only. Guess I'll stick with the pythonic solution for now